# A possible geometric inequality on Jacobian integrals of diffeomorphisms

Tags: riemannian-geometry, volume, diffeomorphism

$\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}$
$\newcommand{\N}{\mathcal{N}}$
$\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}$

Let $\M,\N$ be $d$-dimensional compact connected, oriented, diffeomorphic Riemannian manifolds (perhaps with boundary). Suppose that $d \ge 3$.

Is there a function $F:\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$  such that the inequality

$$ \int_{\M}   (\det df)^{\frac{2}{d}} \text{Vol}_{\M} \ge F\big(\,\int_{\M}   \det df \, \text{Vol}_{\M} \, \,\big)=F\big(\text{Vol}(\N)\big)$$

holds for **every** orientaion-preserving diffeomorphism $f:\M \to \N$?

I allow $F$ to be any positive function. (It can depend on any properties of $\M,\N$).

*There are various equivalent ways to define the determinant of a linear map between oriented inner products spaces, here we can take as a definition

$$ \det df \cdot \text{Vol}_{\M}=f^*\text{Vol}_{\N},$$

So in particular $$ \text{Vol}(\N)=\int_{\N} \text{Vol}_{\N}=\int_{\M} f^*\text{Vol}_{\N}=\int_{\M} \det df  \, \text{Vol}_{\M}.$$